# Remove "Payment method" tab in user profile

Tags: commerce

Commerce don't give me any customize options for the user profile of the user,
I don't want the "Payment method" tab to appear in the user profile, how can I cleanly remove/disable this?

Can someone confirm me if it's work with [tab tamer](https://www.drupal.org/project/tabtamer)?
I read this issue: [How to add / remove tabs from user profile?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/102810/how-to-add-remove-tabs-from-user-profile)
But i can't use it because i have bootstrap barrio as theme and the module have a problem with barrio ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add / remove tabs from user profile?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/102810/how-to-add-remove-tabs-from-user-profile)

Comment: Specifically, see this answer: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/227991/5147  You'll need to add some code to a custom module to remove it if Tab Tamer doesn't work for your theme.

Answer (score 0):

What about simply not granting the "Manage own payment methods" permission? That is a simple solution that doesn't require coding?

Answer (score 0):

this is not a solution, if i change this permission the tab is is from the user profile removed, this is correct, BUT the problem of this permission change is that all users can't select anymore a payment method if they want to buy a product... it is not only for the user page... i solved it with a custom module, but it's sad that Commerce isn't mature enough to solve something like this without extra code either, I've been dealing with Drupal Commerce 2 since D8,D9 for 3 years now and I have to regret this decision... I have the feeling it will never really finished and it's nothing for simple users... the time I've invested... never again a shop with Drupal

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

So having to write a few lines of code means Commerce isn't mature enough? So what is your suggestion? We create an admin page to disable all routes defined by Commerce?

> I've been dealing with Drupal Commerce 2 since D8,D9 for 3 years now and I have to regret this decision... I have the feeling it will never really finished and it's nothing for simple users... the time I've invested... never again a shop with Drupal

So all of this frustration just for a simple problem like this? As far as I know, no-one forced you to use Drupal Commerce... I'm here trying to help you and I'm getting a rant back... And then people complain when they don't get a timely answer...

Comment: I'm sorry, it wasn't meant to be a personal attack, but I've accumulated a lot in these 3 years... It's not your fault, this problem is harmless but I often get frustrated. All ok .. and thank you and the full team for the work on Commerce

Answer (score 0):

I solved it simply in CSS. Drupal is often overcomplicated. Maybe not the "Drupal way" but outcome is the same:

```
.path-user .tabs--primary a[href*="payment-methods"] {
    display: none;
}
```